# Search results in Twitter API dont match Twitter website search results

Tags: twitter

I am using REST API to extract twitter search results in Hindi and Hebrew.

Search phrase in Hindi - "मुझे सपना आया" OR "मैंने सपना देखा की"
Twitter search results return about 100 results for this phrase - https://twitter.com/search?src=typd&q=%22%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%88%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%87%20%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BE%20%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%BE%20%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%80%22%20OR%20%22%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%9D%E0%A5%87%20%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BE%20%E0%A4%86%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%22

However Twitter explorer console API (https://dev.twitter.com/console) returns only 1 result.

Same thing happens for the Hebrew phrase as well. Website returns correct results. API only returns 1 result
Search phrase in Hebrew - "אתמול בלילה חלמתי"

Please Help!!

Thanks,
DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that for Twitter search api results only go back 1 week for exact phrase matches versus keyword matches. So changed my search criteria from exact phrases to separate words to solve the problem.
Here are the links from Twitter discussions which I found related to this topic. 
https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/20596
https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/23726

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question. Probably saved me an hour!

Answer (score 0):

When I try to console (With OAUTH) it returns more than 1 result.
If it doesn't for you try to make the count value higher.

this is my result:
http://pastebin.com/H2HVs71G

***-Tim***

Comment: Tim, that's interesting. I have the count set to 100. I am also using OAUTH. Here is my search criteria URL. https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%20%22%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%9D%E0%A5%87%20%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BE%20%E0%A4%86%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%22%20OR%20%22%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%88%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%87%20%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BE%20%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%BE%20%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%80%22&count=100 IS this what your search criteria URL looks like too?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but, My url is the same! (except from the count=100)

Comment: Thanks Tim, i researched a little on twitter discussions and posted the same question on Twitter and one of the twitter employees replied that the search api goes back only a week for results for exact phrase matches. https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/23726 So i decided that instead of matching exact phrases i would match words and that works well for me